# Generalizations of 'Injectivity on one line'

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, convex-polytopes, jacobian-conjecture

The main result of J. Gwozdziewicz in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9305008) says the following:
"Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, and let $f:k[x,y] \to k[x,y]$, $(x,y) \mapsto (p,q)$, be a $k$-algebra endomorphism
having an invertible Jacobian, namely, $p_xq_y-p_yq_x \in k^\times$.
If there is a line $l \subset k^2$ such that $f$ restricted to $l$ is an injection, then $f$ is an automorphism of $k[x,y]$".

The proof relies on a famous result of [Abhyankar and Moh](https://eudml.org/doc/151610) and on a property of Newton polygons of a Jacobian pair [Theorem 2.1](https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9305008).

> **Question 1:** Can we replace $k$ by any field of characteristic zero, not necessarily algebraically closed? for example $\mathbb{R}$.
>   **My answer:** The answer may depend on whether Abhyankar-Moh theorem is valid over a field of characteristic zero, not necessarily algebraically closed, and this I do not know (please see [my question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295158/generalizations-of-abhyankar-moh-theorem-embeddings-of-the-line-in-the-plane)).

Thank you very much for any comments and hints.

Comment: Regarding Question 1, the Abhyankar–Moh theorem is valid over any field of characteristic zero, and there is even a version over positive characteristic fields that puts conditions on exponents; see the Main Theorem in [Abhyankar and Moh's original paper](http://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl?GDZPPN002190885). The result by J. Lang cited by Gwoździewicz does not need the field to be algebraically closed. Did you find where Gwoździewicz needs that assumption?

Comment: If I am not wrong, algebraic closedness is needed for the implication: $\gamma: t \mapsto (f(t),g(t))$ is injective and $(f'(t),g'(t)) \neq (0,0)$ for all $t \in k$ implies that $\gamma$ is an embedding. (Because, in that case, the D-resultant is a non-zero constant, and then $k[f(t),g(t)]=k[t]$).