# Abhyankar-Moh embedding theorem without algebraic closedness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

After asking [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295158/generalizations-of-abhyankar-moh-theorem-embeddings-of-the-line-in-the-plane/295575?noredirect=1#comment739839_295575), I figured out that I am also interested in the following related question:

> Is [Abhyankar-Moh theorem 1.6](https://eudml.org/doc/151610) still valid if we remove the algebraic closedness assumption?

The answer is probably no, but I do not know how to find a counterexample over $\mathbb{R}$, for example.

Moreover, if I am not wrong, AM theorem 1.6 appears as Theorem 1 of [van den Essen's paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-18487-1_17); I do not see where algebraic closedness is needed in the proof.

Thank you very much for any comments or hints!

**Edit:** I have recently found [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.3064.pdf) beautiful criterion (Theorem 3.3), which does not require algebraic closedness of the base field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the van den Essen's paper, a polynomial map $t\mapsto (x(t),y(t))$ is called an embedding if there is a polynomial $F$ such that $F(x(t),y(t))=t$. There is no problem with his proof: Theorem 1 is true over any field if we interpret embedding in this sense.

The reason why he considered $\mathbb{C}$ rather then an arbitrary field is that the above *definition* is weird if used for not algebraically closed fields such as reals.  (In this case, one might call it something like "strong embedding" or "nice embedding", but just "embedding" would be quite misleading.)

Comment: Thank you very much! Please can you explain what is weird in the definition if we replace $\mathbb{C}$ by $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It is at odds with the common usage of the term. In differential geometry, a map of this sort is an embedding if it is injective and has no singular points. Over complex numbers it is the same as above (even if it is not immediately obvious), but over reals this is a much weaker condition.

Comment: This is  terminology from differential geometry though. I am not sure what  would be the meaning of  "embedding" in algebraic geometry over a general field, if any.   (This isn't my subject.)

Comment: Thank you! I 'thought' that over $\mathbb{R}$ it is also true that $\mathbb{R}[f_1(t),f_2(t)]=\mathbb{R}[t]$ if and only if $f'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is injective. Actually, I was not sure, so I asked this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2698100/a-criterion-for-embedding-mathbbr-in-mathbbr2#comment5573998_2698100

Comment: Unfortunately, your question was a bit vague. Anyway, $(t^2, t+t^3)$ is already a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question. But if I only concentrate on $(t,at+b)$, for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, then obviously it is equivalent to $(t,0)$, since $F(t,at+b)=(t,0)$ for $F:(x,y) \mapsto (x,y-ax-b)$. Anyway, I am now confused about what you said about the geometry criterion being weaker than the algebraic criterion, in contrast to what was suggested in the MathStackExchange question I mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75850/discussion-between-alex-gavrilov-and-user237522).

Comment: Please, in your nice counterexample also $\mathbb{R}(t^2,t+t^3) \subsetneq \mathbb{R}(t)$. I wonder if there is a counterexample with equal fraction fields?

Comment: Although $\mathbb{R}(t^2,t^3)=\mathbb{R}(t)$, it is not a counterexample, since $f'(t)=(2t,3t^2)$ vanishes at $0$.

Comment: No, the fraction field is the same: if $x=t^2$ and $y=t+t^3$ then $t=y/(x+1)$.

Comment: Thank you, nice (I should have noticed this myself..). Please, is there an additional geometric condition $C$ which will make the above two geometric conditions together with  $C$ equivalent to the algebraic condition? (I first thought to add "$f'$ is injective", but in your example $f'$ is injective and the algebraic condition does not hold).

Comment: Honestly, I can't think of any.

Comment: ok. Thank you for your help (I hope that you or someone else will find an additional plausible condition. Perhaps the signs of some derivatives is relevant, perhaps not). The following is another question I have asked, related to our discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733573/why-mathbbcf-1t-f-2t-mathbbct-iff-f-1t-f-2t-neq0-and?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Perhaps the following paper https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2017.1347667?journalCode=lagb20 is relevant; unfortunately, I cannot download it now. From the abstract and keywords it seems that it also talks about D-resultants, probably similarly to what van den Essen and Tutaj did in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404994900833